# Jquery Selector Error, not able to select an element on click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a shortlist box, user will select the elements from one box and it will show up in next box and when user will click on element that is shortlisted, that element will be vanished from the list, everything is working fine, but problem comes when i'm clicking on shortlisted element. Don't know why.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="secondbox">
    <div class="elements">
        Soni
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
        Soni1
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
        Soni2
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
        Soni3
    </div>
</div>
```

JQ:

```
$(".pink").click(function()
    {
        //$(this).remove();
        alert("Hi");
    });
    $(".elements").click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr("class")=="elements")
        {
            $(this).clone().appendTo("#firstbox").addClass("pink");
            $(this).addClass("red");
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
#secondbox,#firstbox{float:left;height:300px;width:300px;border:1px solid black;}
.elements{width:90%;margin:5px;border:1px dashed orange;}
.red{background-color:#d5d5d5;}
.pink{background-color:#BCED91;}
```

Plea

Comment: "but problem comes when i'm clicking on shortlisted element" And that problem is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dynamically creating those elements in the second list, you need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the click event.

```
$(document).on('click',".pink",function () {
    $(this).remove();
    alert("Hi");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KGgY7/)**

Per the docs on `.on()`:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Comment: The keyword here isn't `on`, it's `event delegation`.  You could use `on` this way: `$('.pink').on('click')` but that won't help.  Also, you may want to delegate from `"#secondbox"` instead of `document`

Comment: You missed the point of my comment - I'm saying simply using `on` doesn't help.  You need to use it to delegate the events.  Your answer is correct, but it might help to add a description of event delegation.

Comment: @Dennis - ah so you're agreeing with me? It sounded like you were saying the method I was using was incorrect.

Comment: @j08691 this is the same thing that i wanted... dude can we add one more functionality in this.. on click of .pink class it will be removed and at the same time remove the .red class from respective element..  thanks in advance :)